# Proving even and odd elements of sequence converge to one number

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let’s assume we have a sequence called $a$ when $a_1 <= a_3 <= a_5 <= ...$ and $a_2 >= a_4 >= a_6 >= ...$ and also for any $m$ and $n$, $a_{2m+1} <= a_{2n}$.

How could we prove that if difference of any two sequential elements of the sequence (aka $a_n - a_{n+1}$) converges to zero, sequences $a_{2n}$, $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_n$ all converge to some same number like $l$?

Comment: Sketch: show that $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ are monotonic and bounded, hence both converge. Show that the condition $a_n - a_{n+1} \to 0$ implies that they converge to the same limit. Show that this implies that the full sequence $a_n$ also converges to the same limit.

Comment: @Bungo How should I show that the condition −+1→0
 implies that they converge to the same limit?

Comment: Suppose $a_{2n} \to L$ and $a_{2n+1} \to M$. Then $|L - M| = |L - a_{2n} + a_{2n} - a_{2n+1} + a_{2n+1} - M| \leq |L - a_{2n}| + |a_{2n} - a_{2n+1}| + |a_{2n+1} - M|$. The first and third terms on the RHS can be made arbitrarily small because $a_{2n} \to L$ and $a_{2n+1} \to M$. The second term on the RHS can be made arbitrarily small because $a_{n} - a_{n+1} \to 0$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $|L - M| < \epsilon$, which forces $L=M$.